# CSS only Radio button

Tags: css

I am looking for a CSS-only radio button that works for my following markup. I tried many and could find one to work but the buttons and text beside it are too big.
Here is my HTML:

```
<div id = "quizc", class="chone">
    <h3 class ="quizsub">Question 1</h3>
    <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4> 
    <p>
        <input type="radio" id="rad[1]"rel="0" value="a" name="radgrp0"/>
        <label for="rad[1]">Hello</label>
    </p> 
    <p>
        <input type="radio" id="rad[2]"rel="0" value="b" name="radgrp0"/>
        <label for="rad[2]">World</label>
    </p> 
    <p>
        <input type="radio" id="rad[3]"rel="0" value="c" name="radgrp0"/>
        <label for="rad[3]">Radio</label>
    </p> 
    <p>
        <input type="radio" id="rad[4]"rel="0" value="d" name="radgrp0"/>
        <label for="rad[4]">Television</label>
    </p>
    <input type="radio"rel="0" value="f" name="radgrp0" id="lradio[1]" class="radclr"/>
    <label for="lradio[1]"class="lclr">Clear</label>
</div>
```

The CSS which worked for me is:

```
p > input[type='radio'] {
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    margin:5px 0 0 5px
}
p > input[type='radio']:focus + label {
    color:#C30
}
p > input[type="radio"] + label {
    background:url('radio.png') left top no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 0 50px;
    cursor:pointer;
    line-height:22px;
    min-height:22px;
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:0;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold
}
p > input[type="radio"] + label {
    background-position:0 -200px
}
p > input[type='radio']:checked + label {
    background-position:0 -300px
}
p > input[type='radio']:disabled + label {
    background-position:0 -600px;
    color:#999
} 
p > input[type='radio']:disabled:checked + label {
    background-position:0 -700px;
    color:#999
}
```

New Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/Y9vL7/

Comment: A fiddle would help with this issue.

Comment: Added the link: http://jsfiddle.net/JRJ2w/1/

Comment: With the images in full view: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9vL7/

Comment: This may be a little picky, but you have no consistency when it comes to semicolons at the end of your CSS statements. You tend to leave the last ones off, which is probably valid but inconsistent and bothersome. Also, upon expanding the mass of unreadable CSS, you can see that you have the same style rule twice: `p > input[type="radio"] + label { ... }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated my fiddle with a smaller version for the images and the text.
Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9vL7/2/
Hope this is what you wanted.
If you want to change the size of the images for the checkboxes you need to do some math for the `background-position` in the sprite.

```
p>input[type='radio'] {
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    margin:5px 0 0 5px;
}
p>input[type='radio']:focus+label {
    color:#C30
}
p>input[type="radio"]+label {
    background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPXdm.png') left top no-repeat;
    background-size:22px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 0 30px;
    cursor:pointer;
    line-height:25px;
    min-height:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:0;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold
}
p>input[type="radio"]+label {
    background-position:0 -103px
}
p>input[type='radio']:checked+label {
    background-position:0 -155px
}
p>input[type='radio']:disabled+label {
    background-position:0 -207px;
    color:#999
}
p>input[type='radio']:disabled:checked+label {
    background-position:0 -259px;
    color:#999
}
```

Comment: how you made the images small  I mean the maths behind it.thanks.

Comment: change the background-size to the size you need, then change the line-height and the min-height and after that play with the background-positions of each state so they will looks ok. (I recommend to open the dev tools and play with the positions there because it's easier). Another option is to resize the sprite (a better one in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

So... You can change the font-size attribute.

Search for "font-size" , then lower the size in pixels.

Like this : http://jsfiddle.net/MLK2M/

```
font-size:10px;
```

Comment: He could also play with the `background-size` a bit but then the `background-position` values should be also adjusted.

Comment: Yep. Thing is, I see no true problem with the CSS, only minor adjustments to be made.

Comment: I did but it still occupied a big place due to big buttons. I tried resizing the buttons but it didn't work.

Comment: @swapna did you also adjust the `line-height` on the `p > input[type="radio"] + label` ?

Comment: yes I did, it move text up or down. I have to adjust background-image but I dont know how...

Comment: Controlling you sprites with CSS that much can only lead to problems later down the line. Easiest way is to re-do it with photoshop then build your CSS accordingly.